# ngrok is not forwarding my local host link

Tags: localhost, ngrok, tunnel

i'm running a local host and using ngrok to create a tunnel to my local host but i can't access it via any browser, but i can access my local host

i'm using the library Flask on python to put a local server and i obtained success in that. when i run the code and put the http://[localhost]:[port] in web it runs well.

then i tried using ngrok to create a tunnel that anyone can access my local point. i downloaded the program, i had the authentication token configured and i run the command:

ngrok http http://[localhost]:[port]

then it opened a window i show in the image below with the forward link but my browser cannot reach it. i don't know what i am doing wrong.

[image]

[image]